# How to iterate a deque>>vector>>bytes to a function

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, deque

I need to be able to call a function that is looking for an iterator of a complex data structure (pseudo-code) vector::deque::vector(uint8_t)::iterator. I need to be able to call it with a deque::vector(uint8_t); I can not figure out how to "iterate" it.

In the code segment below, I'm trying to call the MyFunkyFunc function with the someMoreBytes deque structure.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include "stdint.h"

using namespace std;

void MyFunkyFunc(std::vector<std::deque<std::vector<uint8_t>>>::iterator itsIt)
{

}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::deque<std::vector < uint8_t>>> bunchaBytes;
    std::deque<std::vector<uint8_t>> someMoreBytes;

    //... Put at least one element in bunchaBytes

    MyFunkyFunc(bunchaBytes.begin());
    MyFunkyFunc(someMoreBytes); // Problem is here

    return 0;
}
```

This code stub is a close as I can get to the original; I am unable to make any modifications to the MyFunkyFunc function, as it is in a library I have to link with. Many thanks in advance

Comment: **You should really fix the library in that case.** Otherwise you will need to put `someMoreBytes` in a `vector`. It does not make much sense that a function use an iterator as an argument if it process a single item.

Comment: The function that you cannot change, `MyFunkyFunc`, does something when given data from a *`vector`*. You "need" to call it with data from a *`deque`*. What makes you think `MyFunkyFunc` would know what to with a non-vector? (If it's supposed to ignore the vector structure and work on a single element, why does it take an iterator instead of a reference to the element?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that `MyFunkyFunc` was implemented properly as a template accepting an iterator parameter:

```
template <typename I>
void MyFunkyFunc (I itsIt) {
    //...
}
```

Then, you can just pass the address of `someMoreBytes`, since an iterator to a vector behaves the same as the address of an element of a vector.

```
MyFunkyFunc(&someMoreBytes);
```

Otherwise, you will need to redefine `someMoreBytes` to be a single element `vector`, and pass in the `begin()`, just as you did with `bunchaBytes`.

Comment: How, may I ask, do you reference the various aspects of the deque within the template function? How does itsIt translate to the deque to be able to swap, push, etc?

Comment: @Weedware `itsIt` is an iterator. One would normally use a dereference operator on it.